# Linux workflow for browse images + raw edit?

Tags: linux

I'm currently on a Mac using Capture One and have a very simple photos workflow. It is:

- import images, usually raw
- add folder to Capture One
- browse new and existing photos
- edit selected images
- get out, and browse, repeat ...
- back up folder structure to NAS

I don't spent a huge amount of time editing. It's probably 50/50 browse/edit.

The nice thing about this single-app workflow is that the edits I make are visible in the browser. I don't need to do anything in particular, and so the workflow is very fast.

But, I want to move to Linux. And it seems there are a bunch of different programs. They all do their jobs well, but they don't interop with one another. An edit in one program doesn't show up in another.

What's the closest I can get to my desired workflow?

Comment: Aside from using software other than Capture One (e.g. Darktable, RawTherapee, DigiKam, whatever), do you have any significant reason to suspect you can't just continue using the same workflow?

Comment: @twalberg I described my reason exactly: " ... it seems there are a bunch of different programs. They all do their jobs well, but they don't interop with one another. "

Comment: Darktable can approximate that workflow except the backup part. I supplement Darktable with Rapid Photo Downloader. It renames the original out of camera files and writes the original to a second location in addition to writing to my primary disk. I can use cron to rsync the sidecar files to secondary storage.